# Extracting a number from html

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to take the number in the photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8QgC.png) and cut out everything else using Beautiful Soup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id="main_table_countries")


print(results.prettify())
```

Code as is works perfectly, gives me everything from that id, I'm just not quite sure how to then narrow that down to getting that number. Anyone with experience using Beautiful Soup know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just made this yesterday aswell for a discord bot :D,

I used this code to extract the country , this is where all the information was.

```py
def getCountryTable(country):
    countryTable = ''
    for line in getCoronaTable().split('<tr'):
        if line.find(country) != -1:
            countryTable = line

    return countryTable
```

Then I split it in  and manually selected the rows I needed and replaced the leftover things I didn't need.

This is an example:

```py
def getCoronaInfected(countryTable):

    tdList = countryTable.split('<td')

    count = tdList[2].replace('style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">', '').replace('</td> <!--', '')

    return int(count)
```

Comment: If this solution helped you, please upvote so it can help other people too!